# UTF-8 works fine when run in Eclipse JBoss but no success on production server

Tags: hibernate, encoding, persistence, jboss7.x

Is there some special system property that JBoss 7.1 Tools put in JBoss when this run inside Eclipse Kepler that configure the hibernate environment?

I have an application that uses UTF-8 encoding and this persist data using jpa/hibernate (the original version that came with JBoss 7.1), the database on postgress 9 is configured with UTF-8 and the problem is when I run JBoss instalation into Eclipse the accentuation works prety well! But when I run the same JBoss into a CMD or powershell the accentuation stops to work... I was put all configuration that I find in JBoss Tools with parameter on standalone command... but the accentuation don't work.

In my application I put some code to get the value (that is inserted into DB) and write into a file, this permit me verify if data is in correct encoding.

With this I can verify that my application are correctly encoding data, the database is not a problem too. It is only to analyze hibernate, I try to put these sets into persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF8"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF8"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
```

Try with some values variation of UTF8 like UTF-8, uft8 and utf-8. But the problem continue..

I verify too all System Properties into JBoss Management Panel to compare the values when they run into Eclipse and when they run into cmd and it seems ok...!

Any new ideia?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` property to appserver JVM.

Eg. if you are running standalone.sh, then edit standalone.conf. Make sure the above property is included in `$JAVA_OPTS`.